# SQL query selecting columns on the basis of other table in where clause

Tags: sql

I need to write a query that should pull the data from a table on the basis of other table my columns names will also depend on other tables

Lets say I have Table A and B:

```
// Table A
Type_id D1  D2  D3
1   1   2   3
2   12  11  14
3   23  24  15

// Table B
Type_id DC1 DC2
1   D2  D3
2   D1  D3
3   D3  D1
```

Query should be like this:

`select if(type_id=1 then D2,D3) if(type(type_2 then D1,D3) from A where type_id in (select type_id from B) order by if(type_id=1 then D2,D3) if(type(type_2 then D1,D3)`.

I can't fix the type_id = 1, type_id=2 in selecting columns name or in order by because table have lot of type_id and will grow.

So result should be:

```
type_id,columns with respect to (DC1,DC2)
1,2,3
2,12,14
3,15,23
```

Comment: Edited so that the code is readable. You'll need to fix the syntax of the query, however - I am able to help with that if you need.

Comment: you are not running on all these platforms  -- pick the one you are using that will get you an answer that is correct **much faster**

Comment: I wrote table A and B in tabular form for clear understanding but don't know why it's coming in one line.

Comment: Is this a MySQL question, or a SQL Server question. You have both selected, and they're two very different products.

Comment: Doesn't matter sql server, oracle or mysql. I would convert that in my desired db or I will change my DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you want a join and a case statement (or two) here:

```
SELECT 
  A.Type_id,
  CASE
    WHEN B.DC1 = 'D1' THEN A.D1
    WHEN B.DC1 = 'D2' THEN A.D2
    WHEN B.DC1 = 'D3' THEN A.D3
    ELSE 'You got problems'
  END AS DC1,
  CASE
    WHEN B.DC2 = 'D1' THEN A.D1
    WHEN B.DC2 = 'D2' THEN A.D2
    WHEN B.DC2 = 'D3' THEN A.D3
    ELSE 'You got problems' 
  END AS DC2
FROM TABLE_A A
JOIN TABLE_B B ON A.Type_id = B.Type_id
```